# Simple <mat-option> not working. No error in IDE or browser

Tags: html, angular

I am a student trying to learn angular but having some trouble so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Basically I have a mat-form-field with a mat-select. The mat-select shows up in the browser but the options do not drop down. Here's the html and .ts

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Gender">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let Gender of genders" [value]="Gender.value">
      {{Gender.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<!--Form for Gender-->
```

.ts:

```
export interface Gender {
value: string;
viewValue: string;
}

export class SelectGender {
genders: Gender[] = [
   { value: 'm', viewValue: 'Male' },
   { value: 'f', viewValue: 'Female' },];}
```

I have all the Imports already working, but here's the app.module.ts incase:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { PostDetailsComponent } from './post-details/post-details.component';
    import { PostService } from './services/post.service';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    import {
      MatInputModule,
      MatMenuModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatExpansionModule,
      DateAdapter,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatSelectModule,

    } from '@angular/material';
    import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
    import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
    import { PostCreateComponent } from './post-create/post-create.component';
    import { PostEditComponent } from './post-edit/post-edit.component';
    import { PostSigninComponent } from './post-signin/post-signin.component';
    import { MembershipTypesComponent } from './membership-types/membership-types.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'list',
        component: PostDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: PostCreateComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: PostEditComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'membershipTypes',
        component: MembershipTypesComponent
      }
    ];


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PostDetailsComponent,
        PostCreateComponent,
        PostEditComponent,
        PostSigninComponent,
        MembershipTypesComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSelectModule,   //imported for gender picker + membership type
        MatDatepickerModule,     //imported for datepicker
        MatNativeDateModule, //for date picker
        MatRadioModule//radio buttons
      ],
      providers: [PostService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Adding in entire component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
    import { PostService } from '../services/post.service';
    import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-post-create',
      templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css'],
    })
    export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private service: PostService) { }

      onAddPost(form: NgForm) {

        this.service.addPost(form.value.FirstName, form.value.SurName, form.value.Address, form.value.phoneNumber).subscribe();
        //when adding anything here make sure to add it to post.service as well as post.model.ts and server.js/app.post

        console.log(form.value);
        form.resetForm();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    } export interface Gender {
      value: string;
      viewValue: string;
    }

    export class SelectOverviewExample {
      genders: Gender[] = [
        { value: 'm', viewValue: 'Male' },
        { value: 'f', viewValue: 'Female' }
      ]
    }

    export interface type {
      value: string;
      viewValue: string;
    }

    export class MembershipType {
      types: type[] = [
        { value: '1day', viewValue: 'Single Session : €8 / €6.40' },
        { value: '1month', viewValue: '1 month: €30/€24' },
        { value: '3months', viewValue: '3 month: €75/ €60' },
        { value: '6months', viewValue: '6 month: €129/ €103' },
        { value: '12Months', viewValue: '12 month: €199/ €160' },

      ];
    }
```

I've been at it for a while and its probably a stupid Mistake but any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: `*ngFor="let Gender of Genders" ` where is `Genders` in ts? I see only `genders`

Comment: @Smollet777 Yeah Sorry, I had realized that, and changed it to the lower case, not the problem unfortunately. I'll edit that

Comment: did you import the modules in module.ts that is related to component.ts which has this mat-select?

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me - check out this working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwnbhf)

Comment: Yeah I did, they're in the app.module.ts as 
"MatSelectModule } from '(at)angular/material'; " and
"MatSelectModule" in the (at)ngmodule imports @yer

Comment: @Narm That's weird. I took the code from that same stackBlitz with the food and car setup. It's not working in my app though.

Comment: Can you show your actual component code? The component that your `<mat-select>` is being used in? From the code you've provided I don't see you defined a component anywhere. That may be your issue.

Comment: @Narm, I'll add it in the bottom.

Comment: you should import the angular material modules either in SelectGender.module.ts if you have or import the component SelectGender in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that was because of your component `SelectGender`, seems it was not declared in your `@NgModule` metadata.

- **PS**: also I do not see any `@Component` decorator, in that way it is considered as a model more than a component, unless you forget to paste that part.

Here is a working **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-wyfzzj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** where the `AppComponent` is your `SelectGender`.

---

**UPDATE**:

For your updated question, assuming your HTML snippet is a part of `post-create.component.html`, that wont work since you're trying loop over values that doesnt even exist on the relevant TS part (`PostCreateComponent`), you move :

```
genders: Gender[] = [
        { value: 'm', viewValue: 'Male' },
        { value: 'f', viewValue: 'Female' }
      ]
```

To `PostCreateComponent` Ts part merely.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to it all, But through your stackblitz I can't find where you added the SelectGender in the NgModule.

Comment: @JackCaltagirone see updated answer , and for your question I'd mentioned that after `PS`.. :)

Comment: Sorry again, but I have 
`genders: Gender[] =
 [ { value: 'm', viewValue: 'Male' },
 { value: 'f', viewValue: 'Female' } ]` 
In the PostCreateComponent .ts. 
I only have a calling of that GenderArray in the html edit: I'm an idiot at formatting

Comment: Messed around with it a bit, you were right. changed it, all is well. Thank you selem saved me a few hours

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in your component class PostCreateComponent, not outside the component class. Since you declared it outside the component class, it won't be part of the component and that's why you were not able to see the options

```
 genders: Gender[] = [
        { value: 'm', viewValue: 'Male' },
        { value: 'f', viewValue: 'Female' }
      ]
```

Which goes like this:

```
 export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private service: PostService) { }

       genders: Gender[] = [
            { value: 'm', viewValue: 'Male' },
            { value: 'f', viewValue: 'Female' }
          ]

      onAddPost(form: NgForm) {

        this.service.addPost(form.value.FirstName, form.value.SurName, form.value.Address, form.value.phoneNumber).subscribe();
        //when adding anything here make sure to add it to post.service as well as post.model.ts and server.js/app.post

        console.log(form.value);
        form.resetForm();
      }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```